# HTML Form Validation: 'required' tag

Tags: php, html, sql

I am learning PHP/MySQL presently. I made a login and registration system for practice and on the HTML form fields I use the HTML "required".

Is this enough or do I need to write a PHP script to check for empty fields as well?

Comment: Yes you should always validate form inputs on the server side. Never rely solely on the client.

Comment: If you use require tag you dont need chack from PHP is empty.

Comment: @ONLINETELEKOM and if I made a curl post-request, then what?

Comment: @ONLINETELEKOM That's wrong - you should **always** validate on a server-side, no matter what checks you've got in place on the client side.

Comment: @Qirel that dosnt have sense.. HTML5 TAG for REQUIRE is safe and reliable.. you cannt start post withaout write some in filed, why you need some other check?

Comment: @ONLINETELEKOM So what if I use a form of my own and point it to the same handler, or use cURL to send the data? The `require` attribute is fine for client-side validation, sure, but you'll **always** need to validate on server-side. See the dupe linked above.

Comment: @ONLINETELEKOM Request can be sent outside of browser, for example with cURL.

Comment: @ONLINETELEKOM user can inspect element and remove the html required and then skip that input field

Answer (score 4):

> *"Is this enough or do I need to write a PHP script to check for empty fields as well?"*

Direct answer is No.

Details:

Required attribute was introduced in HTML5 to make initial input field validation. But there are number of techniques to hack/violate this validation, also safari browser does not support this, So on safe side use PHP validation as well.

Comment: `required` is HTML5 and will not be supported by browsers not running on HTML5. Safari and IE 8/9 do not support this attribute and some mobiles.

Comment: Yes, I am agree with you and if you look I have also mentioned the same things.

Comment: _So on safe side use PHP validation as well._ NO! Always do PHP validation even if you validated using javascript, because I can turn JS off in my browser and then it would not get dont at all

Answer (score 1):

What do you want to happen if the field is empty?  You need to handle it, but it may be enough to treat it as an empty string and say access denied.

Note that someone could try to use curl or wget so you cannot count on the browser respecting the REQUIRED tag.  And if this is an issue that is security-sensitive then you need to check.

The point here is to insist that a normal web browser not resubmit the form unless the input is filled in.  However, the web server has no knowledge of the form so......